# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "sowohl ... als auch", "entweder ... oder" und "und", "oder"?

Tags: meaning, difference, conjunction

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "*sowohl ... als auch*" und "*und*" in den folgenden Sätzen:

> Wir kaufen Äpfel und Birnen.
>
> Wir kaufen sowohl Äpfel als auch Birnen.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "*entweder ... oder*" und "*oder*" in den folgenden sätzen:

> Wir kaufen Äpfel oder Birnen.
>
> Wir kaufen entweder Äpfel oder Birnen.

Am Ende kauft man beides (Äpfel und Birnen) im ersten Fall und nur eins (Äpfel oder Birnen) im zweiten Fall. Kann man sagen, die Doppelkonjunktionen machen die Sprache nur gehobener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Antwort fällt für die zwei Paare unterschiedlich aus:

### und / sowohl … als auch

*Äpfel und Birnen* bedeutet im Prinzip das Gleiche wie *sowohl Äpfel als auch Birnen*.

Letzteres ist nicht gehobener. Vielmehr ist es eine *Betonung* des Kumulativen, z. B. hier:

> Du solltest ja genau eine Obstsorte kaufen. Was hast du gekauft? Äpfel oder Birnen?
>
> Oh. Ich dachte, ich soll die Obstsorten mischen. Also habe ich **sowohl** Äpfel **als auch** Birnen (= Äpfel ***und*** Birnen) gekauft.

### oder / entweder … oder

Es gibt exklusives Oder und es gibt inklusives Oder. Bloß *oder* zu sagen kann beides heißen. *Entweder … oder* zu sagen meint nur exklusives Oder.

> Oh. Ich vergaß, noch Obst auf den Einkaufszettel zu schreiben. Hast du vielleicht trotzdem Äpfel **oder** Birnen gekauft?
>
> Ja, habe ich.

Hier wissen wir nicht, ob nur Äpfel, nur Birnen oder beides gekauft wurde. Aber gewiss ist, dass nicht weder Äpfel noch Birnen gekauft wurden.

Das ist inklusives Oder.

> Ich mache ein Kreuzworträtsel. Ich brauche eine "Obstsorte mit 5 Buchstaben". Was passt, APFEL **oder** BIRNE?
>
> Es kann nur APFEL sein. Guck mal, du hast doch schon das L!

Das ist exklusives Oder.

> (zu Kindern:) Jeder von euch beiden darf sich eine Frucht aussuchen. Jimmy, bitte nimm dir entweder nur den Apfel **oder** nur die Birne!

Das ist exklusives Oder.

Comment: Die Beispiele sind vielleicht etwas konstruiert, wer würde z.B. sagen _ich vergaß_? Von der Sache her sind sie sehr treffend. Was die beiden _oder_ angeht, gibt es einen Betonungsunterschied: Beim exklusiv gemeinten _oder_ werden beide Alternativen **stark** betont, beim nicht-exklusiven wird die ganze durch _oder_ zusammengehaltene Gruppe gleichmäßig stark und eher beiläufig betont. Es gibt eine dritte Möglichkeit: _Hast du vielleicht trotzdem sowas wie Äpfel gekauft? Oder Birnen?_ - die beiden Alternativen mit Frageintonation, das geht auch in einem fortlaufenden Satz und ist nicht-exklusiv.

Answer (score 0):

Du solltest die Fragen splitten, denn eigentlich sind es zwei, die auch unterschiedlich beantwortet werden müssen.

Zunächst die „sowohl...als auch“ Frage: hier ist es tatsächlich so, dass es zwischen beiden Sätzen keinen semantischen Unterschied gibt. Als einzigen Unterschied würde ich die Verwendung von „Sowohl...als auch“ als etwas gehobeneren Sprachgebrauch bezeichnen als das schlichtere „und“.

Etwas anders gestaltet sich der Fall bei „entweder...oder“: zwar klingt auch hier der ausführlichere Fall etwas „gehobener“, allerdings gibt es hier auch einen minimalen Bedeutungsunterschied: entweder...oder ist eindeutig und unzweifelhaft eine exklusive Unterscheidung: wir kaufen nur genau eines der beiden Dinge. Das pure „oder“ schliesst dagegen nicht kategorisch aus, dass wir auch beides kaufen könnten, also Äpfel UND Birnen. Wie gesagt: umgangssprachlich ist dieser Unterschied minimal und in den meisten Fällen wird jemand tatsächlich das exklusive oder meinen, wenn er nur „oder“ verwendet, aber die Möglichkeit ist eben gegeben.

Comment: Wenn Du meinst, die Frage gehöre gesplittet, dann solltest Du ein Vote-to-close abgeben und keine Antwort liefern, die beides beantwortet.

Answer (score 0):

Ich neige dazu, *sowohl* wortwörtlich zu verstehen, also in irgendeiner Weise Aequivalenz damit auszudrücken:

> Ich kaufte *sowohl* 50 von Äpfeln *als auch* von Birnen

und ich glaube das konnte so wohl als auch in anderer Reihenfolge ausgedrückt werden. So direkt gefolgt von "als" wirkt es heute zumindest aber falsch, daher spare ich mir die weitere Suche. Eventuel kommt *als* dabei weitete Bedeutung zu, insofern es in Vergleich zu *also* gesetzt werden kann; Sicherlich ist es das am wenigsten verständliche Partikel in der Reihe. Ich las letzt in Luther's Hiob, "Also lebte er jeden [Tag]" und hatte mich schon darauf gefreut dies irgendwann passend anzubringen. So oder so könnte man vermuten, das *auch* hätte ein O verschluckt, immerhin wird dies so wiedergegeben in den verwandten nordischen Varianten inkl. Berliner Mundart--wobei dies wiederum die Französische Aussprache *au* /o/ seit den Hugenotten mit beeinflusst hat--was widerum einen Blick auf Fränkisch nahelegt--wo es zudem *und* (Nl *ook*, OE *eke*, Sw *ok*) oder *oder* bedeutet, ok? Ferner ist *al-* sinngemäß verwandt mit *je* (vgl *jedoch* ~ En *although*), En *ever* (*however*, *allerding*, *alldieweil*; gut der Vergleich hinkt), bzw. *any* (*jedenfalls* ~ En *anyhow*; der Vergleich ist zugegebener Maßen nicht *eins* zu einst, was auf ein hoheß Alter der Wendungen hindeutet, so denn nachweißbar; vgl IG *henteros ~ *Helteros, so wohl Lat *alter*, It *altri*, Sp *otres*, bzw Fr *autre* respektive De *ander* [bei Luther noch "zweitens"], En *other*, höchst mysteriös). In bestimmtem Kontext wird *however* als konzessiv bezeichnet; eben würde ich wohl *Äpfel aber auch Birnen* bezeichnen mögen. Wie gesagt kann ich darauf wie aber auch immer so oder so immerhin ansonsten als auch anderweitig jedenfalls jeh nicht genauer eingehen, ja.

Weil *und* prinzipiel Gleichheit oder Gleichzeitigkeit ausdrückt ist "sowohl ... als auch" in aller Regel synonym damit, und bietet zudem den Vorteil die Aufzählung quasi vorher anzukündigen.

Je nachdem, ob der Unterschied beachtet wird, ist die Verwendung entweder gehoben oder auch archaisch, oder aber auch geschwollen. Eine formelle Einordnung mit Verwendungsbeispielen speziell aus der Rechtslehre ist mir leider noch nicht untergekommen.